# Food similar to ice cream, spoons with honey-like substance inside

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

Looking for the title of a book I read as a teenager. The most I remember is a type of food mentioned which was something like ice cream but when you bite the spoon a type of honey like substance came out.

Comment: Welcome to scifi.stackexchange. Can you please elaborate exactly when did you read it, language of the book, any character you remember? That will help people to identify.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/197340/book-in-which-children-escaping-london-get-sent-to-an-alternate-reality (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like *[A Tale Of Time City](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/114520.A_Tale_of_Time_City)* by Diana Wynne Jones. The 'honey' is actually a hot centre to the dessert - called a Forty-Two century butter pie.

**Plot Summary**

> It is September, 1939, the start of World War Two, and Vivian Smith is being evacuated. On arriving at the station, she is kidnapped by two boys, Jonathan and Sam, and taken to Time City, which exists outside of what we know as History. Most of the plot takes place in Time City, the purpose of which is to oversee the course of history and ensure that it stays on its "correct" path. To stop it straying from this path, the Time Police have Observers out in history, tweaking events to make sure that they go the right way.

[A mention of the dessert](https://books.google.com/books?id=BPeOE9HyGVsC&pg=PT67&lpg=PT67&dq=%22tale%20of%20time%20city%22%20spoon&source=bl&ots=whOjubp45G&sig=4FuoEw7hT6agfhGr42p4TcGAJF0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi51L6pyJ_LAhUoMZoKHRHeBu0Q6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22tale%20of%20time%20city%22%20spoon&f=false):

> The ladies came to take away the second course and give everyone frothy little mountains of sweet stuff. Vivian had just dug a spoon into hers -- it smelt as good as butter-pie -- when the door crashed aside to let a wide sandy-haired man pounce into the room. Vivian jumped and dropped her spoon.